# Appium can't locate collapsed element

Tags: wpf, testing, automation, appium

I'm trying to access the Type property of the custom prompt dialog from an automation test. So the element for the Type (text box or text block) is collapsed because no one needs to see it, I just need it for logical processing on automation side.

I don't understand why it can't be located despite being available in the tree. or is there another why to get such access?

XAML:

```
 <controls:PromptDialog ...
                   AutomationProperties.AutomationId="PromptView"
                   d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=viewModels:PromptViewModel}">


<Grid Margin="{StaticResource MarginThickness}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="{StaticResource Gutter}" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--Prompt-->
    <Grid Grid.Row="0"
          Visibility="{Binding IsShowingPrompt, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="4" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="{StaticResource Gutter}" />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <!--Image-->
        <ContentControl Grid.Row="0"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Content="{Binding}">
            <ContentControl.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:PromptViewModel}">
                    <Image Name="Image" />
                   //displaying image per type
            </ContentControl.Resources>
        </ContentControl>

        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0"
                      Grid.Column="2"
                      Focusable="False"
                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                      MaxHeight="400">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock behaviors:TextBoxHyperlinkBehavior.Text="{Binding Text}"
                           TextWrapping="Wrap"
                           Focusable="False"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                           FontFamily="{Binding Font.Name}"
                           Foreground="{Binding FontColor}"
                           AutomationProperties.AutomationId="PrompView_Text" />
                <TextBox Visibility="Collapsed"
                           Text="{Binding Type}"
                           AutomationProperties.AutomationId="PromptView_Type" />
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
        

    <!--Commands-->
    <UniformGrid Grid.Row="2" Rows="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        // buttons
    </UniformGrid>
</Grid>
```

</controls:PromptDialog>
Appium:

```
public IVisualElement Type => _appiumSession.CreateVisualAppiumElement("PromptView_Type");
```

Or

```
public AppiumWebElement Type => _appiumSession.FindElementByAccessibilityId("PromptView_Type");
```

WPF Snoop:
[image]

Error:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException : Timed out after 10 seconds
    ---- OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
```

Any pointers are highly appreciated,
thanks

Comment: Collapsed pieces of ui are not in the visual tree. They are not rendered.

Comment: There's both a logical and visual tree in wpf.  A collapsed uielement is in the logical but not the visual tree.

Comment: @Andy any way to access the logical element?

Comment: You can walk the logical tree but you should first understand what it is. Google and read the msdn documentation carefully. Thing is though. Why are you not rendering a uielement you need to test? That doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: the Type isn't useful for end user so there's no need to show it, the info is represented in prompt image (error, warning, etc). but I need it for test. I thought it would be like PHP hidden tag equivalent. I'm searching and reading the documentation in parallel to this question maybe I can save some time. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know anything about Appium, but the problem could be solve with .net automation api very easily.

```
        // Must find top window of app first or could cause overflow easily.
        var topWindow = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children,
        new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, "Id of top window"));

        // Find out your target element if it's in visual tree, whatever it's collapsed or not.
        // You can also Find out another element in the middle first to reduce the search work.
        var target = topWindow.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants,
        new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, "PromptView_Type"));

        // retrieve the value.
        var val = ((ValuePattern)target.GetCurrentPattern(ValuePattern.Pattern)).Current.Value;
```

You have to add reference to UIAutomationClient.dll and UIAutomationType.dll to make this code work.

---

**Update for .net core app**

For .net core(3.0, 3.1, 5.0), there's a huge difference about how an automation peer answer inquiry than .net framework app. Automation peer will not answer inquiry if it's offscreen(control's visibility had been set to collapsed or hidden) unless inquiry was targeting raw view. So we have to force inquiry target to make it works.

```
        var topWindow = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, "Id of top window"));
        AutomationElement target = null;
        var cr = new CacheRequest()
        {
            TreeFilter = Automation.RawViewCondition,
        };

        using (cr.Activate())
        {
            target = topWindow.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, "PromptView_Type"));
        }
```

Comment: thanks for the information. I tried this but `target` is still getting null. I added a middle element to reduce the search like in your comments but still getting null

Comment: do you have any resources about finding target element "whatever it's collapsed or not" I couldn't find anything on Microsoft documentation.

Comment: @Katia There's nothing about how visibility effects searching result on documentation, but you can do some simple test to confirm that. What I'm curious about is that can you find out any ancestor of the target like the `StackPanel` or the `Grid` you had show in WPF snoop's screenshot with my code?

Comment: I did test it, when the element is visible your code works but if it's collapsed it's null. I also added a middle step between the `topWindow` and the `target to get the parent prompt element and it is found. it's hard to believe that I'm the first one to face this and it harder with no relevant documentation I've been searching this for a while now. thanks again for your input

Comment: @Katia It's very odd because I can find the element whatever is collapsed or hidden with those codes. My code doesn't work only when the element is not in the visual tree, like in a `Page` that haven't being navigate to or within a `Expander` which was not expanded. Can you show me more code around this `PromptView_Type`?

Comment: @Katia With the code you provided, the problem must be the 2nd Grid which its Visibility was set to a `Binding` which initial value must be `Collapsed`. In WPF, if a `UIElement` was loaded with `Collapsed` visibility, then all it `ContentPresenter` descendants will not present the content, so your target will not be brought into visual tree at the beginning. To deal with this situation, you must wait for the visibility of the grid change to other value at least once, than use my code to find your target.

Comment: If that was the case, then `PrompView_Text` shouldn't be accessible either as it's on the same level as `PromptView_Type`

Comment: @katia Yes. I have put your code into a window with minimum modification and did some test. If the grid start with collapsed visibility, both `PrompView_Text` and `PromptView_Type` were inaccessible. But in other cases, both `PrompView_Text` and `PromptView_Type` were accessible. And with the information I got, this is the conclusion I can provide.

Comment: @ katia Are you using .Net 5.0 on WPF side?

Comment: @katia Or any other .Net Core Version like 3.x?

Comment: thanks for testing it out, it's good to know the problem lays elsewhere

Comment: @katia Happy to help. And also sorry for short sighted in .net framework only before.

Answer (score 2):

There were several times when I used **Snoop** and it found more elements/attributes that Appium can access.

That is why now I am using [Accessibility Insights for Windows](https://accessibilityinsights.io/docs/en/windows/getstarted/inspect/). Of course you can use [inspect.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/inspect-objects), but **Accessibility Insights for Windows** is the recommended from Microsoft. You can also try [WinAppDriver UI Recorder](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2018/06/20/introducing-winappdriver-ui-recorder/) that is generating XPaths.
If your element is not present in **Accessibility Insights for Windows** Appium will not be able to locate it.

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.visibility?view=net-5.0

Collapsed elements are not rendered and NOT in layout.

Why not to use Visibility.Hidden instead, or Visibility.Visible with height of 0px.

Comment: Hidden elements take up space, so that might make the UI look strange with hidden elements with verticla spacing where none is expeccted (between multiple lines). How would you set back the original height after setting the height to 0px depending on the state?